# Trying to save an altkey to a CMD or BAT file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to delete a folder with no name created with an Alt key 0160.. Now I', trying to save that to my CMD for automation purposes and I just can't save it. It acts as if im looking for an 'a' with apostrophe. How can I save an Alt Key to a CMD file properly?

Answer (score 1):

You can directly include the value in your batch script simply typing the value the same way you did in the command line, something as `set "var=`<kbd>Alt+0160</kbd>`"`

If your editor or your environment (pagecodes, charsets) interfere, you can use a little autogenerated script to get the problematic character

```
@echo off

    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    call :getChar 160 myVar
    echo [%myVar%]

    exit /b


:getChar asciiCode returnVar
    for %%a in ("%temp%\%~nx0.%random%.tmp") do (
        >"%%~fa" echo WScript.StdOut.Write Chr(%~1^)
        for /f delims^=^ eol^= %%b in ('cscript //nologo //e:vbscript "%%~fa"') do set "%~2=%%b"
        del /q "%%~fa">nul 2>&1
    ) & exit /b
```

There are limitations in what `for /f`, or `set` command can handle and what can be included inside a variable so it will not work for all the possible characters but in your case it should work.

Comment: I would like to try this one

Answer (score 0):

I think it's only possible building a simple console app in C# or C++, which would must be executed from CMD console (.exe file).